# jquery how do i collect the content of an iframe each time the iframe changes state?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I am working on a project which i will like to collect the content of an hidden iframe and make it the html of a div each time the iframe changes state while loading so it will act like the page is redirected and downloading its contents, but the heading and footing of the page will not refresh as well.

A good example is how facebook keep their heading and footing fixed while redirected.

i have achieved collecting the iframe content to the div using `onload`, but the problem is that, the content will not fully download from the iframe before collected i.e images, `.css` files and `.js` files.

Here is a code i tried:

**THE SCRIPT USED TO COLLECT THE CONTENT WHEN LOADED**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function frame_loaded(){
         var content=$('#iframe_id').contents().find('#body');
         $('#my_div').html(content);
}
</script>
```

**AND THE FRAME**

```
<iframe id="iframe_id" src="some_url.php" style="display: hidden;" onload="frame_loaded()"></iframe>
```

**AND THE DIV**

So i used `setTimeout()` to slow time for 1 second so the frame will load the content and execute it's scripts fully before collecting it.

Here is the code:

```
setTimeout(function(){
 $('#my_div').html(content);
},1000);
```

At times the content still won't complete downloading it's content from the iframe before collected.

I don't have any idea how to listen to the iframe if it's fully loaded or listen to it's ready state.

If any one can tell me the best way to do this, it will be very appreciative because i am very new to this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would suggest using [portholejs](http://ternarylabs.github.io/porthole/) which will help you interact with the iframe(domain xyz.com) and you can pass messages in between the iframe(domain xyz.com ) and the page which holds it (domain abc.com).For example in your case when the iframe loads you can pass a boolean (from  xyx.com )to your page(abc.com) which holds the iframe and then download the content there is working example of how it porthole works [here](http://sandbox.ternarylabs.com/porthole/).
Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

kind of "stupid" but try this (i don't have your code so it's a bit "hard" for me

```
$(document).on('load','#iframe_id',function(){
    var content = $(this).content().find('#body');
    $('my_div').html(content);
})
```

Comment: Thanks But I have tried that several times, still acting the same!

Comment: i will look for another solution

Comment: why use an iframe? it will work perfectly fine with a simple ajax call no?

Comment: Still same as `$('#iframe_id').load()`, but what i really meant is to listen to every `<a>` click event, prevent it's default action by stopping it from redirecting the visitor and load the the `<a>` `href` atribute to the iframe and collect it's content to the div!

Comment: I used the iframe because i want the browser to display progress bar and loading icon, so if it takes time, the visitor will understand that it is coming from his connection.